# Jackson ObjectMapper in Jersey has error with multi thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jackson, jersey-2.0

I have an application used jersey 2, Jackson (jersey-media-json-jackson) with ObjectMapper.

When threads access the same service at same time, the serialization fails and some objects are serialized in empty, like {}.

Example:

```
{"order":1,"itens":[{"id":91},{"id":85},{"id":32},{"id":19},{"id":58},{"id":98},{"id":75},{"id":78},{"id":84},{"id":79}]} 
{"order":1,"itens":[{"id":77},{"id":9},{"id":83},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]} -> bug
{"order":1,"itens":[{"id":71},{"id":94},{"id":58},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]} -> bug
{"order":1,"itens":[{"id":4},{"id":4},{"id":73},{"id":48},{"id":57},{"id":47},{"id":60},{"id":22},{"id":44},{"id":48}]}
```

My code:

```
@provider
@Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ObjectMapperResolverJ2 implements ContextResolver <ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperResolverJ2 () {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper ();

        mapper.setSerializationInclusion (JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        mapper.enable (DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS);

        mapper.enable (DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);
        mapper.enable (DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_INTEGER_FOR_INTS);

        mapper.disable (SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);

        mapper.disable (SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS);

        mapper.disable (DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        mapper.configure (SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        mapper.setVisibility (PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setVisibility (PropertyAccessor.SETTER, Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setVisibility (PropertyAccessor.GETTER, Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setVisibility (PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.getVisibilityChecker (). withFieldVisibility (Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.getVisibilityChecker (). withSetterVisibility (Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.getVisibilityChecker () .GetterVisibility (Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.getVisibilityChecker () .with (Visibility.ANY);

       
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext (Class <?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

}
```

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

        public MyApplication () {

            register (JacksonFeature.class);
            register (ObjectMapperResolverJ2.class);
        }

    }
```

Service

```
@GET
    @Path ("/{Order}")
    @Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public OrderDTO getOrder (@PathParam("Order") Integer code) {
         // I change return to simplify
         OrderDTO order = new OrderDTO();
         order.setOrder(1);

         List<ItemDTO> itens = new ArrayList<>();

         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            ItemDTO item = new ItemDTO();
            item.setId((int) (100 * Math.random()));
             itens.add(item);
         }

         order.setItens(itens);

         return order;
    }
```

Jersey version: 2.21
Jackson version 2.5.1
Tomcat 7.0.59

Comment: `@Path ("/ {Order}")` is the space intentional?

Comment: You'll have to debug`findOrder` and see why it returns some empty items. it looks like a bug...

Comment: @Path ("/ {Order}") is failed to copy source

Comment: @alfasin i put a log with toString of OrderDTO and log was ok.

Comment: Then use a sniffer and see that the response that comes from the server looks good on the client side before the client reads it. Further, assuming the issue is indeed on the client-side, you provided only the server code which is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @alfasin I used jmeter and PostMan to simulate the problem, to eliminate possible problems with clients.

Comment: Are you suggesting the the problem is not in the client and not in the server? :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source for this OrderDTO class and show how it's being created and populated.

Comment: The `code` property of your items is probably null, if there is a thread safety issue it is in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I tested on the versions Jersey version: 2.0, Jackson version 1.9.11 and Tomcat 7.0.59 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem changed the way ObjectMapper is registered, before

```
register(ObjectMapperResolverJ2.class);
```

After:

```
JacksonJaxbJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
provider.setMapper(getObjectMapper());
register(provider);
```

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication () {

        register (JacksonFeature.class);
        //register(ObjectMapperResolverJ2.class); 

           JacksonJaxbJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
            provider.setMapper(getObjectMapper());
            register(provider);
    }


    private ObjectMapper  getObjectMapper(){
        ObjectMapper  mapper = new ObjectMapper ();

        mapper.setSerializationInclusion (JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_INTEGER_FOR_INTS);

        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);

        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS);

        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.getVisibilityChecker().withFieldVisibility(Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.getVisibilityChecker().withSetterVisibility(Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.getVisibilityChecker().GetterVisibility(Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.getVisibilityChecker().with (Visibility.ANY);

        return mapper;

    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to 'solve' it is to use the ThreadLocal, so each thread will use its own copy

```
private static final ThreadLocal<ObjectMapper> objectMapperThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = objectMapperThreadLocal.get();
    if (objectMapper == null) {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapperThreadLocal.set(objectMapper);
    }
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Comment: ObjectMapper is supposed to be threadsafe. Something like this shouldn't be necessary, and there's a good chance the OP's actual problem has nothing to do with the object mapper.